# Move to the beginnig/end of line (not in bash)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, text-cursor

In macOS, from any "textbox" for instance the one in which I am writing this question, if I press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> the cursor goes to beginning of the line. Furthermore in macOS, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> the cursor goes in the beginning of the line again, in fact in macOS <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects everything, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is still available.

How can do that in Ubuntu?

I would also like to have something equivalent to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>, that is "delete all the line".

Comment: I think `home` and `end` keys of the keyboard are the buttons meant for that, which is how that functions are implemented in Windows, as simply pushing `home` would go the beginning and `end` to the end of the line, while combining them with `ctrl` key would do the same for the whole page, the entire text that is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a textbox, I think the only way is by pressing home/end. But if you are talking about a terminal, I would recommend using set -o vi. For me is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Look for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> buttons on the keyboard. They will do the job.

For multi-line textboxes, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to reach the beginning and end of text.

To delete everything, first select the text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the previous word, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the line your cursor is in equivalent to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

To move to the beginning or end of a line, the `home` and `end` keys are used. On a macbook, those keys are usually bound to `fn + leftArrow` and `fn + rightArrow`. If that does not work, sources suggest using `fn + option + leftArrow/rightArrow` or other combinations.